# Ambiguity between field in an Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, compiler-errors

I have following interfaces (located in NuGet package)

```cs
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    Task<int> SaveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default (CancellationToken));
}

public interface IRepository<TAggregate, TKey> where TAggregate : class, IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{
    IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
}

public interface IEfRepository<TAggregate, TKey> : IRepository<TAggregate, TKey>
        where TAggregate : class, IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{
    Task SomeMethod(CancellationToken token = default);
}

public interface IAggregateRoot<TKey>
{
    TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

csproj of a nuget package looks like that:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
        <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
        <Version>2.0.0</Version>
        <AssemblyVersion>2.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <DebugType>Full</DebugType>

        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and in my Infrastructure project (which is referenced by Service project) I have following interface and implementation:

```cs
public interface IDocumentRepository : IEfRepository<Document, int>
{
        
}

public class DocumentRepository : Repository<Document, int>, IDocumentRepository
{
    public DocumentRepository(
        WriteDocumentsContext writeDocumentsContext
    )
        : base(writeDocumentsContext)
    {

    }

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; }
    public Task SomeMethod(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class Document : IAggregateRoot<int>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<T, T1>
{
    protected Repository(WriteDocumentsContext writeDocumentsContext)
    {
        
    }
}

public class WriteDocumentsContext : DbContext
{
}
```

When I try to invoke `UnitOfWork` like that:

```cs
public class D 
{
    private readonly IDocumentRepository _documentsRepository;
    public D(IDocumentRepository docRepo, IDocumentRepository documentsRepository)
    {
        _documentsRepository = documentsRepository;
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        await _documentsRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveAsync(token);
    }
}
```

and csproj of my Infrastructure project looks like that:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="MyNugetPackage" Version="2.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup> 

</Project>
```

and csproj of my Service project looks like that:

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\Infrastructure\Infrastructure.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup> 

</Project>
```

I get following error:

```
DeleteDocumentCommandHandler.cs(58, 48): [CS0229] Ambiguity between 'IRepository<Document, int>.UnitOfWork' and 'IRepository<Document, int>.UnitOfWork'
```

But when:

- I move `DocumentRepository` and `IDocumentRepository` files to the service project, everything works just fine.
- When I inject `IEfRepository<Document, int>` instead of `IDocumentRepository` also everything works just fine.
- When I add generic constraints on `IDocumentRepository` it still doesn't work.
- I add to the Infrastructure project csproj following lines

  ```cs
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
  ```

  It works...

I'm using .net core 3.1 and try to compile project by `dotnet build`, in Rider IDE and Visual Studio 2019.

Side note:
When I remove the `nullable = enable` from a NuGet package, also everything works just fine.

EF Core version: 3.1
Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Target framework: NET Core 3.1
Operating system: Windows 10 Pro/Home
IDE: Dotnet console, Jetbrains Rider, Visual Studio 2019

[Reproduction](https://github.com/MNie/EFCoreNullableIssue)

## Side Note

There is no additional code here. Repository does **not** implement IRepository.

Comment: Does your Repository class implement IRepository also ? Than you have two implementations in your DocumentRepository.

Comment: No, it is not a problem here.

Comment: your IEFRepository implements IRepository, and your IDocumentRepository implementrs IEFRepository, then your base Repository itself also implements that interface. Either you need to remove one, or work with explicit interface implementations.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker interfaces don't implement anything, they just enforce something to be implemented. And the repository class isn't visible, you are also just guessing ?

Comment: Your right, i meant extends. And yes, i am guessing that the repository class also extends that interface. it's the only logical explanation for this problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove `IDocumentRepository` from `public class DocumentRepository : Repository<Document, int>, IDocumentRepository`?  I think Glenn might be onto something as on paper it looks like it should work, but it is quite heavy on the interface re-inheritance...  IMO a bit of KISS is needed and it smells of trying to abstract out EF which I highly do no recommend as it comes at the cost of either forgoing many of the advantages EF brings, or adding a *lot* of complexity to try and leverage them where something simpler would give you that with far fewer headaches.

Comment: @StevePy fully agree that it isn't the best idea, but it is a part of legacy part of an app that I don't want to rewrite right now (I have plans for that, but I don't want to make a big changes + move to a .net core 3.1 from 2.2 in a single sprint).

If I remove the interface `IDocumentRepository` nothing happens, Problem persists. When I look at decompiled code I see some `nullable` attributes on classes, so I assume this is a problem with a combination of C# 8 `nullable` + ef core(?).

Comment: It looks as it is a bug in Roslyn and should be fixed in the near future. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/41179